# Upgrading numpy+MKL library

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip, intel-mkl

When I try to run my program, I get this error

```
from . import _tifffile
Runtime error: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa
```

When  I upgrade my numpy installation using

> pip install numpy --upgrade

the numpy version is matching but the updated numpy library replaces my numpy+MKL and I get this error

```
> from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
> ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL'
```

How to upgrade my numpy_MKL library?

Comment: are you on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to my answer to another question here: [RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054531/runtimeerror-module-compiled-against-api-version-0xc-but-this-version-of-numpy/48123076#48123076)
and upgrade to pandas version 0.21.0
`pip install pandas==0.21.0` and run your test again.

But if you are on `Windows` try downloading the binary from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy
and install it using `pip` and run your test again.
Unfortunately I don't have a Windows machine to verify that.