# RuntimeError and AttributeError while trying to import Keras (Numpy Corruption)

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, python-3.6, uninstallation

I have already tried a few solutions mentioned in GitHub and Stack Overflow forums, such as [RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054531/runtimeerror-module-compiled-against-api-version-0xc-but-this-version-of-numpy), but I am still unable to solve this problem after trying out different solutions. The problem is that when I import keras or tensorflow, it will give the save error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
2019-04-22 20:04:47.663759: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675] Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr 
Abort trap: 6
```

No matter I try it on my Terminal, Jupyter Notebook, after changing the versions of tensorflow and numpy various times, it still outputs the same error.

MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra
Python 3.6.8

At the moment, I have Python 3.6.0 installed on my Macintosh disk and Python 3.6.8 installed on my Anaconda (somehow I couldn't clean some parts of my Anaconda). Tensorflow should be 1.13.1. Currently, my Numpy version is 1.13.3. I have tried 1.12 and 1.14 variations, non of seem are able to work. As for Keras, it is version 2.2.4.

If I use Python 3.6.0, the error is:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 960, in _find_and_load
SystemError: <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with an error set
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'declare_namespace'
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried from [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48054531/1233251)? Which versions of numpy, Keras, and TensorFlow are effectively installed at the moment?

Comment: @E_net4 At the moment, I have Python 3.6.0 installed on my Macintosh disk and Python 3.6.8 installed on my Anaconda (somehow I couldn't clean some parts of my Anaconda). Tensorflow should be 1.13.1. Currently, my Numpy version is 1.13.3. I have tried 1.12 and 1.14 variations, non of seem are able to work. As for Keras, it is version 2.2.4.