# incompatible packages when trying to run tensorflow example code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to run some example code found on [keras](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_weather_forecasting/). When I run `import tensorflow`, I get an error

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
```

Then when I `import pandas`, I get the error

```
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054531/runtimeerror-module-compiled-against-api-version-0xc-but-this-version-of-numpy), there is some incompatibility between the pandas, numpy, and tensorflow packages. I tried some of the suggestions in that post like installing specific versions of pandas and numpy, but I still get errors. (I'm using WinPython 64 bit v.3.9.4.0) Any suggestions?

Note: I have packages `numpy 1.19.5`, `pandas 1.2.4`, `tensorflow 2.5.0`.

Comment: what's your pandas and numpy version?

Answer (score 1):

When you install a package, the dependencies are automatically installed with the good version. I recommend you to uninstall all of these libraries and then run `pip install tensorflow`. It will install the correct version of numpy. Then install the latest version of pandas with `pip install pandas`.